# Trying to add numbers within my MongoDB database

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, bots

So I've been trying to make this "work" command for my economy/fun bot. No luck adding the 5 cash to the database...

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["work"])
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def Work(self, ctx):
    results  = collection.find({"_id": ctx.author.id})
    for result in results:
        await ctx.send("Great job, you've been paid 5 cash.")
        collection.update_one({"_id": f"{ctx.author.id}"},{"$set":{"Cash": 5}})
```

Comment: Use `$inc` instead of `$set`

Comment: Tried it... but nothing actually happened. No errors, no update on the MongoDB Database :\

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is updating in your database because your queries are different:

- `{"_id": ctx.author.id}` → you're searching for an int id.
- `{"_id": f"{ctx.author.id}"}` → you're searching for a str id

As @Barmar said, you should use `$inc` instead of `$set`.
You can also use `update_many` instead of `update`:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['Work'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Great job, you've been paid 5 cash.")
    collection.update_many({"_id": ctx.author.id}, {"$inc": {"Cash": 5}})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and help, both of you.